# How to open and show contents of .html file with android application in browser in android application

Tags: html

How to open and show contents of .html file with android application in browser in android application..

I have used

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); 

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl("file:////android_asset/www/index.html");

//  webView.loadUrl("android.resource://com.project.testhtml5/"+ R.raw.index);  

}
```

}

But when I run this app every time on the android emulator   Iam seeing  error"Web Page Not available"

The web page at  file:////android_asset/www/index.html   might be temporarily down  or it hmay have  moved permannetly to a new web address.

the path for the first time and when I click on the link again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i cant find anything wrong in your code... but you have a typo...

```
webView.loadUrl("file:////android_asset/www/index.html");
```

should be

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

you should have three slashes instead of four... maybe this will do the trick